# Ошибка при установке codebox

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, npm

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема при установке codebox через npm на ubuntu 16. Ниже лог.

```
wizaxxx@DevSrv:/$ sudo npm install -g codebox
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.7: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.1.14: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.1: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
npm WARN lifecycle safefs@3.1.3~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) safefs@3.1.3 node ./cyclic.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/safefs-21f7bf6d
npm WARN lifecycle typechecker@2.0.8~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) typechecker@2.0.8 node ./cyclic.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/typechecker-bc3c138b
npm WARN lifecycle ambi@2.1.6~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ambi@2.1.6 node ./cyclic.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ambi-d7219fb2
npm WARN lifecycle taskgroup@3.3.9~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) taskgroup@3.3.9 node ./cyclic.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/taskgroup-6a2c81e0
npm WARN lifecycle ambi@2.2.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ambi@2.2.0 node ./cyclic.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ambi-b2202ca5
/usr/local/bin/codebox -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/bin/codebox.js

> pty.js@0.2.5 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/gittle/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/gittle/node_modules/pty.js/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:190:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:74,
                 from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static NanIntern::FactoryBase<v8::Signature>::return_t NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::New(NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH, int, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH*)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:181:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH&, int&, NanIntern::Factory<v8::Signature>::FTH*&)’
   return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
                                                                            ^
In file included from /home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node.h:42:0,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:24,
                 from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/v8.h:4675:27: note: candidate: static v8::Local<v8::Signature> v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>)
   static Local<Signature> New(
                           ^
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/v8.h:4675:27: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 4 provided
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:0:
../../nan/nan.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan.h:165:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../../nan/nan.h:160:25: note: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../../nan/nan.h:557:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../../nan/nan.h:557:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../../nan/nan.h:561:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../../nan/nan.h:561:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../../nan/nan.h:568:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:25:0,
                 from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed:
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:0:
../../nan/nan.h:568:67: error: invalid conversion from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’ [-fpermissive]
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:25:0,
                 from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/home/wizaxxx/.node-gyp/4.2.6/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
In file included from ../src/unix/pty.cc:16:0:
../../nan/nan.h:568:67: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../../nan/nan.h:572:29: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                             ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../../nan/nan.h:579:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
../src/unix/pty.cc: In function ‘void PtyFork(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)’:
../src/unix/pty.cc:185:34: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int chdir(const char*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
       if (strlen(cwd)) chdir(cwd);
                                  ^
pty.target.mk:96: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pty/src/unix/pty.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/gittle/node_modules/pty.js/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/gittle/node_modules/pty.js
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN headless-terminal@0.4.0 requires a peer of screen-buffer@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "codebox"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! pty.js@0.2.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pty.js@0.2.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pty.js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pty.js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty.js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: https://community.runabove.com/kb/en/instances/how-to-install-the-codebox-ide.html  вы делали как тут говорится ?

Comment: Да сделал все в точности как тут говорится. Но этап установки codebox не проходит.

Comment: *Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0* — перевод: обновите *lodash* до версии 4.0.0